# Error building my Ionic React app in Android due to 'invalid source release: 17' - how can I solve it?

Tags: android, react-native, ionic-framework, build.gradle, capacitor

I am trying to build an Ionic React app in Android and am not succeeding. The app works perfectly fine in the browser but won't build. I used the followings steps:

1. ionic capacitor build
2. npx cap add android
3. ionic capacitor sync android
4. ionic capacitor open android

Right now the project wont build properly - the Gradle build will run, but it wont properly work as it states "Cause: error: invalid source release: 17 "
I tried to change the java version in the build.gradle file to 16 but it still stated the same error for 17.

i also modified the capacitor.build.gradle to 16 and it still states the same error.

this is how the build.gradle file looks right now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace "ionic.io.starter"
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ionic.io.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Android Studio are you using? I ran into a similar issue using Capacitor and this helped me: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/5-0

> Capacitor 5 requires Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 or newer because of the usage of Gradle 8, that requires Java JDK 17. Java 17 ships with Android Studio Flamingo. No additional downloads needed!

I had the same error until I updated to the new version of Android Studio Flamingo. Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the installed version of your JAVA SDK in following gradle files and then try to build,

< project >\android\app\capacitor.build.gradle

```
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

< project >\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build.gradle

```
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

It may helps you